# Keras in R: high accuracy model predicts same output class

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I've recently started experimenting with Keras in R, and built a simple prediction model. I'm getting reasonable accuracy ~85%, but the model predicts the exact same outcome for every entry in my test data.

Input data is made up of 1000 rows, and 46 columns of numeric indicators (scaled to be between 0 and 1).
Outcome (i.e. y variable) is composed of two columns, namely "WIN" and "LOSE", with values of either 1 or 0. if "WIN" is equal to 1, then "LOSE" must be equal to 0.

Model structure:

```
`model <- keras_model_sequential()
 model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(46)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 25, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.05) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.05) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 6, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.05) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "softmax")`
```

I then run the model with the following:

```
model %>% compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",optimizer =optimizer_rmsprop(),metrics = c("accuracy"))    
history <- model %>% fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, validation_split = 0.2)
```

I then analyse model accuracy with the following, getting a result of 85%:

```
model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test,verbose = 0)
```

Finally I make some predictions:

```
model %>% predict_classes(x_test)
```

Where "x_test" is made up of 500 rows, also with 46 numeric columns. The prediction output I get with the above line of code is a vector equal to the number of rows in "x_test", but all with values = 1 (which I know can't be true, as this would not yield accuracy of even close to 85%).

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your dataset balanced or do you have a rare class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *bet* that, as cdeterman hints at the comments, your dataset is highly *imbalanced*, i.e. you have much more 1's in your training set than 0's.

In such cases, accuracy as a metric is meaningless, and you should use precision, recall, and the confusion matrix instead - google "class imbalance" for more.

Just as an extreme example, if 85% of your training labels are 1's, you can have a 85% (training) accuracy "classifier" simply (and naively) by classifying all samples as 1 (which, arguably, is not what exactly you are looking to do).

Comment: Thanks for this, was exactly the problem!